# How to lock a button using a checkbox?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a checkbox that should be initially inactive. And there is also a button that should be inactive. If the checkbox becomes active, then the button also. And vice versa.

ts:

```
  disabled: boolean = false;

  changeEvent(event) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.disabled = true;
    }
    else {
      this.disabled = false;
    }
  }
```

html:

```
<mat-checkbox color="primary" (change)="changeEvent($event)">
    Disabled
</mat-checkbox>

<button mat-button color="primary" [disabled]="!disabled">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can refer to the checkbox itself instead using a component variable

```
<mat-checkbox #disabler color="primary">
    Disabled
</mat-checkbox>

<button mat-button color="primary" [disabled]="disabler.checked">
  Click
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove target inside the condition.

```
disabled: boolean = false;

  changeEvent(event) {
    if (event.checked) {
      this.disabled = true;
    }
    else {
      this.disabled = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can shorten this by saying `this.disabled = event.checked`

Answer (score 0):

When using attribute disabled, you have to supply the literal value, or omit the attribute. Can you try:

```
<button mat-button color="primary" [disabled]="disabled ? 'disabled' : null">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic *should* work (as proven in [this quick Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-32eyvh) I've done):

**component.ts**:

```
disabled = false;

change(event) {
  this.disabled = event.target.checked;
}
```

**component.html**:

```html
<input type="checkbox" (change)="change($event)">Disabled
<button [disabled]="!disabled">Click</button>
```

Are you missing some Angular Material imports or containing elements?

Answer (score 0):

why do you not use [(ngModel)]?

```
<mat-checkbox[(ngModel)]="disabled">Disabled</mat-checkbox>
<button [disabled]="disabled?true:null">Click</button>

//in your .ts
disabled: boolean = true;
```

Comment: What if he is using reactive forms?

Comment: `[disabled]="myForm.get('mycontrol').value?true:null"` I use only .value, not myForm.get('mycontrol').value==true because in case of checks is the same